# How do I disable user interaction with a JSlider?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, immutability, jslider

I have a JSlider and I want to make it so I can not move it with my mouse. Instead I have set the Slider to interact with update methods determined by observables. So if slider is 3 one time and then I click a JButton and some value changes to 4 the Slider moves.

The Slider already functions like this, but what I need is a way to make it so I can't move it with my mouse. I can't

```
//pseudo

JSlider slide = new JSlider(0, 4, e.getVal) //val is 3
//JSlider can't move with mouse
//call update
void update()
 slide.setValue(e.getVal); //val is 4
```

This is a basic idea of what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Why you can't just disable it use [setEnabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) method?

Comment: Because I never heard of that before is the honest answer haha
There's easily 100+ concepts in the full program I'm implementing, a lot of it is just researching. Could I ask how I would invoke setEnabled in this case?

Comment: Put `slide.setEnabled(false);` after initialization of `slide` variable.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I do slider.setEnabled(false);
Thanks for the tip!